# Is it even possible to make NSPopver fully transparent?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover, nscolor

I tried my hands on changing the color of NSPopover, I am able to change to it all desired color except transparent.

As, it is known that NSPopover is by default semi transparent. I tried changing the NSWindow color directly, by Layer as well, I also tried setting the NSView's color to transparent i.e. NSColor.Clear but no luck.

So the question is - Is this possible to change the background color of NSPopover to transparent?

Answer (score 1):

No this is (sadly) not possible.